# Want to add icon on Button, drawableTop is not working Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable, android-button

I want to add call icon on **Button** but drawableTop is not working.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:drawableTop="@android:drawable/ic_menu_call"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: and also using your same code I'm able to see `drawableTop`

Comment: Actually I am using android:drawableLeft and that is also not working.

Comment: Is there a case that your drawable's tint color is the same as the background color?

Comment: are you by any chance using new material library instead of design support library?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace your `Button` with `AppCompatButton`

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:drawableTop="@android:drawable/ic_menu_call"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: are you using new material library inplace of support libarary?

Comment: I am using com.android.support:design:28.0.0

Answer (score 2):

when using androidx with the material ui library instead of the support library

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```

you will need to use

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableTop="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"
    android:text="Camera" />
```

Comment: Do you know the reason we need to use drawableTop instead of icon?

Answer (score 1):

Add orientation to your `LinearLayout`, decide if you want to set `android:layout_weight` while setting `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` and `android:layout_height="match_parent"` and set text to your button.

Answer (score 1):

You can also define the icon in **drawableStart** like in this way:

```
                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@color/black_overlay"
                        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_menu_call"
                        android:padding="15dp"
                        android:text="Click here"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
```

The padding, text style and background color is only for the decoration.